# How to set value in input field to empty by click on a button in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**How to set value in input field to empty by click on a button in react js ?**
I thought it is an easy step to empty an input field by click on button, though it is easy but my code is not working. I m using Ant design onSearch input field. I want that when I click on CloseCircleOutlined button, the input field must be set to empty. Kindly help me to solve this issue.
Here is my code:

```js
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  
  
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setSearch(value);
  }
  
  const onSearch = () => {
       if(search){
        mutation()
        setisSearched(true);
  }
      setCurrentPage(1);
    }
    

const handleCloseButton = (e)=>{
setSearch(" ")

  }
    
   <SearcI want thath
      enterButton="Search"
      size="large"
      placeholder="Search Product"
      className="search_bar"
      onSearch={onSearch}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      />
      
         <Text>Showing results for {`"${search} "`}  <CloseCircleOutlined onClick={handleCloseButton}/></Text>
```

Comment: You need to assign `search` as the input's `value` for this type of change to be reflected. AKA [2-way data binding](https://reactjs.org/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html)

Comment: sorry, I put wrong question first. Now i have edited kindly check the code again

Comment: The answer is still the same BTW, but I see that [Evren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13544849/evren) also answered it so it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you already set to empty string but you do not use that parameter in your search component. You should use value

```
<Search
      enterButton="Search"
      size="large"
      placeholder="Search Product"
      className="search_bar"
      onSearch={onSearch}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      value={search}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I realized that I did not use Value attribute. Now it is working. Thanks a lot for your quick response